# can i save Image with textview on album?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

My question is how can i save Image with textview in album ? 
i mean when i rite on image i want to save the image with the textview i write it 
[Click to see the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7uc8.gif)

and here is my code but doesn't work

```
@IBAction func SaveImage(_ sender: Any) {
        let imageRepresentation = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cv1image.image!)
        let imageData = UIImage(data: imageRepresentation!)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageData!, nil, nil, nil)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Completed", message: "Image has been saved!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

it's work but the text doesn't saved 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C9xn.gif)

Comment: What's does it mean "Doesn't work"? Can you provide any error log or describe better the behaviour?

Comment: @araknoid i mean doesn't save in album

Comment: Is the photo saving but without the text view? or is nothing being saved at all?

Comment: @LoganHenderson is nothing saved

Comment: Have you gotten permission to access the users photo library. You will need to add a NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in your info.plist

Comment: @LoganHenderson thank you it's saved , but saved without text

Comment: are you adding the textview as a subview to the imageView

Comment: no i add as textview i drag and drop just like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must make the textView a subview of the UIImageView. However this is not possible to do in storyboards. The simplest way to accomplish what you want is to use a UIView as a container view, add the image view and textview as subviews, then you can snapshot the UIView using the function below. Your storyboard document outline should look like this

[image]

```
   func snapshot(view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size)
        let savedFrame = view.frame;
        view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        view.frame = savedFrame;
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image
    }
```

So you should change your IBAction to the following. You must grab a reference to the UIView that contains both elements. I called it "containerView" in the below code.

```
@IBAction func SaveImage(_ sender: Any) {
        let image = snapshot(view: containerView)
        let imageRepresentation = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
        let imageData = UIImage(data: imageRepresentation!)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageData!, nil, nil, nil)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Completed", message: "Image has been saved!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: it's work but the text don't saved the background of textview it's saved but the text doesn't saved , i want when user put some text and clicked save button all the text and image saved , i hope you understand me

Comment: I don't understand. Maybe if you added a photo to your question to show what you mean

Comment: i add photo you can see what i mean

Comment: Have you tried dismissing the keyboard before you click save. You might want to make sure the text views didEndEditing method is called before save is pressed